track each activity execution duration in azure data factory
I have one question in azure data factory.
How to track each activity execution time, and maintain log entries in audit log table.
example : one pipeline contain 20 activities, and we need to track each activity to see how much time it takes and load that information into into audit log table.
auditlog table :
pipleine|runid  | activityname      | starttime           |endtime             | duration
first    |azxde | copydataacitvity  |2024-02-10 10:20:10  |2024-02-10 10:30:10 | 10 minutes
first    |azxdee|lookupactiviey     |2024-02-10 30:20:10  |2024-02-10 32:30:10 | 2 minutes
first    |azxdee|DataFlow           |2024-02-10 35:20:10  |2024-02-10 36:30:10 | 1 minutes

Please tell me how to archive this task in azure data factory to maintain custom logs.
Create an audit log table in the database and table structure like below .
audit log table:
pipleine|runid  | activityname      | starttime           |endtime             | duration

